# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.(Parameter 'arch')

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb

I am running **vscode** for **c++** on ***lenovo legion 5***, **win 10**, and when trying to run a cpp by f5, I get an error:

"Unable to start debugging. Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.(Parameter 'arch')"

The launch json is:

````
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.cpp",
            "environment": [],
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "customLaunchSetupCommands": [
              { "text": "target-run", "description": "run target", "ignoreFailures": false }
            ],
            "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
            "linux": {
              "MIMode": "gdb",
              "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe"
            },
            "osx": {
              "MIMode": "lldb"
            },
            "windows": {
              "MIMode": "gdb",
              "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGw/bin/gdb.exe"
            }
          }
        
    ]
}```

I'm a beginner so I don't really know why this is happening.
````

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that the architecture of the launch is incorrect. I think that VSCode infers the architecture if you do not specify it, and in this case, the architecture that it inferred does not match what you actually have.

Try adding: `"targetArchitecture": "YOUR_ARCHITECTURE",` to the configuration. On a Lenovo, I am guessing that you have `arm64` as your architecture, but you may check your system information to be sure.

So for example, you could change the configuration to look like:

```
...
"MIMode": "gdb",
"targetArchitecture": "arm64",
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
...
```

(Where exactly you put the target architecture in the configuration should not matter as long as it is not inside another field.)

Comment: Thank you for replying! Man it was so annoying that I just switched over to Visual studio IDE lol